# Is markdown ruby available only on Japanese SE or is it available all across Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

In response to this question, [Is there any difference between 旅行者 and 旅人?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/73405/is-there-any-difference-between-%e6%97%85%e8%a1%8c%e8%80%85-and-%e6%97%85%e4%ba%ba), the answerer used ruby for the two pertinent words. I was delightfully surprised to find it's accomplished with simple, self-explanatory markdown:

> 「旅行者{りょこうしゃ}」

and

> 「旅人{たびびと}」

Japanese SE ignores attempts to do ruby with HTML:

> 「旅行者りょこうしゃ」

and

> 「旅人たびびと」

I can't imagine why I would need ruby on Math SE or other Stack Overflow sites, but it would certainly be nice if I happened to need it and it was available. Or it could even be, for all I know, a standard feature of markdown.

So, what is the availability of markdown ruby outside of Japanese SE?

Comment: As far as I know, Ruby is not available outside of Japanese SE. [We're trying to get it over at Chinese SE](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315/should-we-add-the-enhancement-from-japanese-se-for-furigana-ruby-text-here-for-a), and it's apparently over on the Community Management Team's backlog.

Comment: @droooze I just tried to use it on Math.SE (I discarded once I saw it didn't work), but of course I can't see it being useful there. On Chinese.SE, on the other hand, I can imagine it would be quite useful, e.g.,「旅行者{lǚrén}」... oops, it doesn't actually work for pinyin, though maybe that's only because it's got some kind of check for hiragana...

Comment: That syntax you've used only works for Ruby on one character. You have to use a  slightly different one for Ruby across multiple characters:「[旅行者]{lǚxíngzhě}」is achieved by 「\[旅行者\]\{lǚxíngzhě\}」(character \ escapes; remove them)

Comment: @droooze Ah, I see: 「[旅行者]{lǚrén}」. Getting a little off-topic, I got that pinyin off Google Translate. Is it correct?

Comment: No, lǚrén is 旅人.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby markdown is an add-on, thus it needs to be manually requested and enabled.

That said, other than this (Japanese.SE) site, [Anime.SE](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/673/can-we-get-furigana-support-here) also supports ruby.